# Sed command to replace values on custom lines

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm trying to replace custom values in a configuration file using sed, but the changes should be applied for specific indexes of lines (e.g. first two lines only, line 3, etc).

For now, using this command will replace all of the matching values with the desired one:

```
sed -i"" -e "/PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER =/ s/= .*/= ${BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER};/" ${CONFIG_FILE}
```

Here is how my file looks like:

```
**** more config ****
                **** more config ****
                PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = <to_be_replaced>;
                **** more config ****
                PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = <to_be_replaced>;
                PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.bash.sed.test;
                PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.bash.sed.test;
                **** more config ****
    **** config ****
    PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.bash.sed.test;
**** config ****
```

I've tried adding `/g2` line GNU sed, but this won't work on. Any ideas or workaround to do this using bash would help me a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: So you only want the change the first two matches, but not any later one?

Comment: First two matches, but an universal solution for multiple indexes would be ideal:)

Comment: Are you using the standard sed or the GNU version?

Comment: I'm using OS X sed version.